# What is the correct way to implement a getDerivedStateFromProps in a functional component that uses effects?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am not even sure if I'm asking the right question here, but my basic problem is that my child components are rendering before my parent component can dispatch actions to update the redux store, so my child components are accessing properties that don't exist. I think it will be more clean with an example such as this:

**Simplified Redux Store:**

```
{
  "error": null,
  "fetched": false,
  "fetching" : true,
  "data": {
    // could be wildly different based on what URL is called (actions, params etc)
  }
}
```

I have a higher order component around my ChildComponents that listen to the 'fetched' property in the store before rendering. My ParentComponent is responsible for dispatching fetchData requests. This is a simplified example of what it looks like:

```
function ParentComponent(params) {  
  const [state, setState] = useState();
  const {router} = props;
  const newDataToFetchObj = shouldGetNewData(router, state.dataToFetch) // returns null or object which fetch props;

  // This is simplified logic, I have something that will dispatch the fetch only when necessary based on the URL
  if (newDataToFetchObj && newDataToFetchObj !== state.dataToFetch) {
    // This dispatch will FIRST change the store "fetched" property to false, then set fetching to true
    // Then it fetches the data asynchronous and later again updates the store
    dispatch(fetchData(newDataToFetchObj))
    setState({dataToFetch: newDataToFetchObj})
  }

  // Now, by the time the child component is rendering, fetched will be set to FALSE, so my spinner will show up
  return {
    if (newDataToFetchObj.list) {
      return <ChildListComponent />
    }
    return <ChildCardComponent />
  }
}
```

Now, the problem is that while this setup works, since react 16.13.1 I've been getting a warning that state is being updated outside an efffect method. I've figured out that the problem is the `dispatch` call in the body. So I've changed the setup like so:

```
function ParentComponent(params) {
  const [state, setState] = useState();
  const {router} = props;
  const newDataToFetchObj = shouldGetNewData(router) // returns null or object which fetch props;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (newDataToFetchObj && newDataToFetchObj !== state.dataToFetch) {
      // The problem is that this won't be dispatched until after the render, so the children will render and the prop fetched will be true
      // This causes rendering errors as the data for the right component has not been fetched yet.
      dispatch(fetchData(newDataToFetchObj))
    }
  },  [newDataToFetchObj])  

  // I'm getting errors now when you navigate around, because the fetched: is not set to false in time
  return {
    if (newDataToFetchObj.list) {
      return <ChildListComponent />
    }
    return <ChildCardComponent />
  }
}
```

**Warning: Cannot update a component (`ConnectFunction`) while rendering a different component (`App`).**

So my main question is, I thought that my first way of doing this, was essentially implementing a getDerivedStateFromProps setup? But React was complaining about it. But If I warp my dispatch events in useEffect, they are dispatched too late. It's like the URL will change, the components will re-render, then the data will be decided to be fetched. This flow doesn't make sense.

Any tips in the right direction would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Correct. You should *almost* never trigger state updates in the middle of rendering a component.

The only exception is [calling a `useState` setter or `useReducer` dispatch for that component to mimic `getDerivedStateFromProps` inside the component itself](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-do-i-implement-getderivedstatefromprops).

Since dispatching Redux actions actually results in updates to other components outside the scope of this one, it's not legal to dispatch Redux actions while rendering.

In general, you'll need to restructure your components so that the children either aren't rendered at all until the data they need is available, or have them be more defensive in how they select data from the store in case the data isn't there yet.

Comment: Hm I am not really sure how I would go about changing this. The URL change, needs to trigger something before the components render down. I can't I can't have URL Change > Render > Get Data. I need to have URL Change > Get Data > Render. How do other people deal with this flow?